# Ordenar un FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase

Hola estoy realizando una app que muestra los dias de la semana procedientes desde FireBase, el problema es que los tengo desordenados y quiero que se ordenen.

He buscado en muchos sitios y ponen ordenar con el método sort del adapter:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906464/sort-listview-with-array-adapter

El problema es que yo no puedo utilizar este método porque utilizo un FirebaseRecyclerAdapter de [esta biblioteca](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/firebase-recyclerview), el qual deriva de un Adapter , que no tiene el método sort.

Al final he podido ordenar los datos del adaptador pero cuando lo muestro solo se muestra el último elemento y los anteriores no. Os pongo el código:

El adaptador:

```
public class MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DiaFiestaMeta, MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView.MyFireViewHolder>
    implements View.OnClickListener {
private View.OnClickListener listener;
private List<DiaFiestaMetaFecha> dias;
private static List<TextView> views ;
private DiaFiestaMetaFecha fechaDia;

public MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView(Class<DiaFiestaMeta> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<MyFireViewHolder> viewHolderClass, DatabaseReference ref) {
    super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
    dias = new ArrayList<>();
    views = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Override
public MyFireViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fila_diasfiesta_layout, viewGroup, false);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    MyFireViewHolder holder = new MyFireViewHolder(itemView);
    return holder;
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (listener != null)
        listener.onClick(view);
}

@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(MyFireViewHolder viewHolder, DiaFiestaMeta modelo, int position) {
    fechaDia = new DiaFiestaMetaFecha(modelo.getUidDiaFiesta(), modelo.getTituloDiaFiesta());
    dias.add(fechaDia);
    if (this.getItemCount() == position + 1) {
        viewHolder.bindDatos(dias);
    }
}

public static class MyFireViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView textoTv;
    private int num;



    public MyFireViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textoTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTituloDiaFiesta);

        views.add(textoTv);

    }

    public void bindDatos(String titulo) {
        textoTv.setText(titulo);
    }

    public void bindDatos(List<DiaFiestaMetaFecha> dias) {
        burbuja(dias);
        for (int i = 0; i < dias.size(); i++) {
            views.get(i).setText(dias.get(i).getTituloDiaFiesta());
        }
    }


}
```

}

Y el Fragment donde lo utilizo:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    uidsFiestas = getUidsFiestas();
    //Por defecto mostramos la ultima fecha
    uidFiestaSeleccionada = getUltimaFiesta();
    adaptadorFiestas = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, uidsFiestas);
    //Ponemos el uidFiestaSeleccionada el primero para que nos lo muestre
    adaptadorFiestas.remove(uidFiestaSeleccionada);
    adaptadorFiestas.insert(uidFiestaSeleccionada,0);
    mDataBaseDiasFiestaSelRef = mDataBaseFiestasRef.child(uidFiestaSeleccionada).child("diasFiestas");
    adaptadorDiasFiestas = new MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView(DiaFiestaMeta.class, R.layout.fila_diasfiesta_layout, MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView.MyFireViewHolder.class, mDataBaseDiasFiestaSelRef);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fiestas_layout, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    spFiestas.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView textoTv = (TextView) view;
            uidFiestaSeleccionada = textoTv.getText().toString();
            //fiestaSeleccionada = crearFiesta(uidFiestaSeleccionada);
            mDataBaseDiasFiestaSelRef = mDataBaseFiestasRef.child(uidFiestaSeleccionada).child("diasFiestas");
            adaptadorDiasFiestas = new MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView(DiaFiestaMeta.class, R.layout.fila_diasfiesta_layout, MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView.MyFireViewHolder.class, mDataBaseDiasFiestaSelRef);
            adaptadorViejoDiasFiestas = (MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView) recView.getAdapter();
            recView.setAdapter(adaptadorDiasFiestas);

            if (adaptadorViejoDiasFiestas!=null)
                adaptadorViejoDiasFiestas.cleanup();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
    spFiestas.setAdapter(adaptadorFiestas);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    recView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recView.setAdapter(adaptadorDiasFiestas);
    return view;
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Me tomé la libertad de agregar un enlace a la biblioteca que estas usando  para clarificar la pregunta aun más para los demás. En el futuro te recomiendo de hacerlo siempre cuando tienes un problema que involucra artefactos que no son parte de las bibliotecas comunes. Facilita encontrar la solución, si el problema esta dentro del código e tercer parte (que es el caso aquí).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para solucionar el problema con el ordenamiento de tu adapter, tienes que revisar la herencia de tu adapter: asumo que usas el `com.example.matteo.firebase_recycleview.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` (avisame si estoy equivocado por favor).

Esta clase extiende el `RecyclerViewAdapter`, y implementa algunos métodos para manipular los datos dentro del apdapter, pero más importante aun es la manera como guarda internamente las vistas y sus claves. Si revisas el código [aquí](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/firebase-recyclerview/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/matteo/firebase_recycleview/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java), te das cuenta que esta implementación guarda las vistas y las claves a las vistas en listas de tipo `ArrayList`. Eso significa que si no quieres destruir la relación entre las vistas y sus claves, que vas a tener que implementar el ordenamiento paso a paso, para no perder la vinculación de los indices. Como te das cuenta, no un trabajo especialmente eficiente.

Así mi recomendación es lo siguiente:

- implementa `DiaFiestaMeta` con un método `getKey()` que te permite generar la clave desde tu item.
- implementa la interfaz `Comparable` para `DiaFiestaMeta`
- implementa un método `ordenar` en tu adapter que usa `Collections.sort(List<T> lista)` para ordenar los datos, luego generas las claves y llamas a `notifyDataSetChanged()` para actualizar la vista.

Tu método `ordenar()` debería terminar siendo:

```
public void ordenar(){
    Collections.sort(getItems());
    ArrayList<String> keys = getKeys();
    for (int i = 0; i<getItems.size(); i++){
         keys.set(i, getItems().getKey());
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Cualquier duda con la implementación, no dudes de preguntar por comentario.